# First item in excel omitted in results (DataSet, OleDB)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dataset, oledb

[Sample.xlsx]

```
Column 0, Row 0 = "ItemA"    
Column 0, Row 1 = "ItemB"    
Column 0, Row 2 = "ItemC"    
Column 0, Row 3 = "ItemD"
```

[Application]

```
DataSet dsData = new DataSet();    
string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Sample.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;'";    
OleDbDataAdapter daGetExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", strConn);    
daGetExcel.Fill(dsData);        

foreach (DataRow row in dsData.Tables[0].Rows) 
{ 
    lbExcelData.Items.Add(row[0].ToString()); 
}
```

`lbExcelData` is a ListBox control on the form.

[RESULTS]

> "ItemB", "ItemC", "ItemD"

[PROBLEM]

Why is the first item, "ItemA", being ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Excel, set HDR=NO in the Extended Properties setting of the connection string.

"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Sample.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO'"

http://connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

Comment: To clarify, this is because the first row is being interpreted as the column names.

Comment: You should pay attention to put single quotation, if you have just one parameter for extended properties before HDR=NO.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your connection string in this case should be:

```
string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
    Data Source=Sample.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;'";
```