# OleDb Connection not reading all the rows from excel file

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string, oledb, oledbconnection

I am using an OleDb in C# connection to read data from an Excel sheet. And fill it in a Datatable.

The sheet contains 275 rows and 27 columns. After I read it, Rows 1,2 and 3 are empty. All the other rows are filled correctly.

Anyone have an idea on the problem?

Here is my code:

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                "Data Source=" + "C:/Sheets/DataSheet.xls" + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

string Query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, objConn);

DataTable Table = new DataTable();
objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmd;
objAdapter1.Fill(Table);
```

Comment: Even I encountered such problems. You can refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913497/unknown-problem-while-exporting-excel-to-system-datatable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941083/problems-reading-in-an-excel-file-in-c also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913497/unknown-problem-while-exporting-excel-to-system-datatable Make Sure your connections are proper http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that my sheet contained mixed data and it was only reading numbers.
The solution is to specify

```
Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1\";"
```

IMEX=1 allow the reader to import all data not only numbers

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715220/first-item-in-excel-omitted-in-results-dataset-oledb) has some information on the first row being treated as a header, unless you specify `HDR=NO` in the connection string.

I am not sure why the 2nd and 3rd rows might be skipped however; is there any difference in their contents that you can see?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I know that the first row is a header and did not count it. it is filling the header correctly but the next 3 rows are not filled. And no there is no difference in their content

Answer (score 0):

I just added new row to upper row and it appears in dataset. So rows orders changing solved problem in my case